# nvidia-smi is executed every 5 sec -- is it normal?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04

I was looking through `lastcomm` output and found out that command `nvidia-smi` is executed by current user (who's name is just "user") about every 5 seconds. I am curious if it is a normal situation or not? Details follows:

```
# lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
# uname -srvmpio
Linux 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

then

```
# lastcomm nvidia-smi
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:14
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:14
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:14
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:14
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:14
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:14
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.01 secs Fri Jan  1 17:14
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:13
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:13
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:13
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:13
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:13
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:13
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.04 secs Fri Jan  1 17:13
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:13
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.01 secs Fri Jan  1 17:13
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:13
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:13
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:13
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:12
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:12
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:12
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:12
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.01 secs Fri Jan  1 17:12
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:12
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:12
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:12
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:12
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:12
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:12
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:12
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:11
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:11
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:11
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:11
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:11
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:11
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:11
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:11
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:11
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:11
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:11
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:11
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.04 secs Fri Jan  1 17:10
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.03 secs Fri Jan  1 17:10
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:10
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.01 secs Fri Jan  1 17:10
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:10
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:10
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:10
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:10
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:10
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:10
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:10
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:10
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 17:09
```

I deleted here huge portion of the output because nearly the same goes until the start:

```
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 07:39
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 07:38
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.04 secs Fri Jan  1 07:38
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 07:38
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 07:38
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 07:38
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 07:38
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 07:38
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 07:38
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 07:38
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 07:38
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 07:38
nvidia-smi             user     __         0.02 secs Fri Jan  1 07:38
```

Of course user does not run `nvidia-smi` manually. So, is this situation normal and who and why runs it so frequently?